# Spring JDBC, Could not open ServletContext resource

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I don't understand why this code do not work. I followed the guide steps by steps by the site "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_injecting_collection.htm" perfectly. Can you help me?

The class that throws the exception:

```
public class UserJDBCTemplate implements UserDao {
private DataSource dataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

@Override
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    System.out.println(dataSource.toString());
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);     
}

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
enter code here
 @Override
public void create(String first_name, String last_name, String role,   

String password, String username, String email, String avatar, String`enter code here` chat_code) {     
    String SQL = "insert into user (first_name, last_name, role, password, username, email, avatar, chat_code) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?)";
    jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, first_name, last_name, role, password, username, email, avatar, chat_code);
      //log.info("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age)     
}
```

This is the dispatcher servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />   
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wbm.bug_presents" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is the contextApplication:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
   <bean name = "dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wbm_bug_track_svil"/>
      <property name="username" value="eugen"/>
      <property name="password" value="eugen"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="addBugJDBCTemplate" class="com.wbm.bug_presents.JDBCTemplate.AddBugJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
   <bean id="chatBugJDBCTemplate" class="com.wbm.bug_presents.JDBCTemplate.ChatBugJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
   <bean id="removeBugJDBCTemplate" class="com.wbm.bug_presents.JDBCTemplate.RemoveBugJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
   <bean id="userJDBCTemplate" class="com.wbm.bug_presents.JDBCTemplate.UserJDBCTemplate">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
```

And this is the web.xml file

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>bug-presents</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/contextApplication.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext    resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
... 21 more

mag 09, 2016 9:28:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext            listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance     of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5251)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at
```

Comment: What is the name of file with `contextApplication`?

Comment: contextApplication.xml  https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2A281DB5E99811CC!40935&authkey=!AIewjN38ScVBDbw&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem is mentioned in exception it self:

> Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

As you wrote in commentary, your configuration file name is `contextApplication.xml`, so you have to change it to `applicationContext.xml`.